# Qual conteúdo mais apropriado para colocar no header ou no nav?

Tags: html5

Eu estou criando uma pagina que tem o logo e o nome dela no `header`, e um menu com `links` para outras paginas utilizando listas no `nav`, mas eu não estou colocando `nav` dentro do `header`, eu coloquei todos eles dentro de uma `div` com um `class` menu, é certo fazer desse jeito? ou seria melhor colocar o `nav` dentro de `header`, e em vez de eu utilizar a `div`, usar uma `section`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certo ou errado nesse caso não existe. Existe o **recomendado** segundo as especificações do `HTML5`.

No `HTML4` pelo fato de todas as seções semânticas com a tag `<div>` fazerem parte da estrutura do documento, não há formas de haver seções que contenham informações relacionadas não ao documento em si, mas ao site no geral, como logos, menus, tabelas de conteúdos, copyright ou avisos legais. Com esse propósito, o `HTML5` introduz três novos elementos:

- `<nav>` para coleções de links (tal como uma tabela de conteúdos)
- `<footer>` e `<header>` para informações relacionadas ao site.

Perceba que `<footer>` e `<header>` não são conteúdos de seção como o `<section>`, ao invés disso, eles existem para delimitar semanticamente partes de uma seção.

---

Voltando agora para o seu universo, a tag **nav** é comumente utilizada para criar menus pois representa um conjunto de links. Então sim você faz bem em utiliza-la em seu menu. 
Quanto a coloca-la dentro da tag **header**, é totalmente a seu critério, pois o menu representa de certa forma a estrutura do seu site, e se enquadra no recomendado para o conteúdo dessa tag "*informações relacionadas ao site*".
Por fim, sobre utilizar **section** ou invés de **div**, isso pode ser uma boa prática, caso a `div` em questão represente uma seção do seu site. Exemplo:

```
<div class="corpo-da-pagina">
    <!-- Todo o conteúdo da sua página -->
</div>
```

No caso acima seria recomendado segundo as especificações do `HTML5` usar uma tag `section`.

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando algum `framework`?? tipo `boostrap` ou algum outro??
Se tiver, tem q verificar na documentação deles, pois cada `framework` segue uma hiearquia junto com `CSS` q se vc não seguir pode ficar bagunçado na sua tela.

Se não tiver usando nada, estiver criando tudo do 0, ai não tem modo errado de fazer, pode ser em `div` como pode ser dentro tags específicas como `header`, isso vai ser só uma questão mesmo de organização do seu código. Mas o q fará a diferença é o modo q vc vai tratar tudo no seu estilo.

Comment: Na verdade, acredito que ele está querendo dizer por questões de `semantica`

Comment: Então, é difícil responder sem saber o q realmente ele está fazendo e o q está utilizando. Eu tenho estruturas de páginas q criei, onde utilizo o header somente para o logo e poucas informações, e o nav dentro de outras divs, ou vice e versa. Tudo depende mesmo do resultado q ele quer exibir na tela e da organização dos códigos com ou sem frameworks. Pelo menos é assim q eu vejo.

Comment: Na verdade, a semantica tem sim uma estrutura a se seguir
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp